# extract words with specific character sequence

Tags: python, regex

I have a list of strings. I only want to extract the words within each string that have a specific character sequence.

For example

```
l1=["grad madd have", "ddim middle left"]
```

I want all the words that have sequence "dd"

so I would like to get

```
[["madd"], ["ddim", "middle"]]
```

I've been trying patterns of the form

```
[re.findall(r'(\b.*?dd.*\s+)',word) for word in l1]
```

but have had little success

Comment: Do you need a regex?

Comment: I'm thinking along the same lines as quamrana, if you convert the strings at l1[0] and l1[1] into lists (splitting them by the space") then you can loop through them with: if "dd" in...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use list comprehension for this. You don't need regex to accomplish what you're trying to do.

[See code in use here](https://tio.run/##HchBCsMgEAXQvaf4uEkCpRC67klCFgNfm4HRiEqhpzeku8crv36c@TWGre/Nf6oQSUgc8g3@AU9qQlLSAizE7ndXquY@bw3xrBBohq1/t9vybMW0zws0YiKnO9u@OOfGuAA)

```
l1=["grad madd have", "ddim middle left"]
print([s for a in l1 for s in a.split() if 'dd' in s])
```

This loops over `l1` and splits each value by the space character. It then tests that substring to see if it contains `dd` and returns it if it does.

Answer (score 1):

You were close, you'll want to match word characters 0 to many times with `\w*`:

```
[re.findall(r'\w*dd\w*', word) for word in l1]
```

Comment: The regex is incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this Regex : `\b\w*dd\w*\b`

[Regex101 Demo.](https://regex101.com/r/hEWSob/1)

Comment: The correct expression with this would be `[re.findall(r'\b\w*dd\w*\b', x) for x in l1] `

Answer (score 0):

Try this in one line:

```
l1=["grad madd have", "ddim middle left"]

print(list(map(lambda x:list(filter(lambda y:'dd' in y,x.split())),l1)))
```

output:

```
[['madd'], ['ddim', 'middle']]
```